# $q.all returns only 1 object (angular ionic app)

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I have the following function:

```
$q.all([Timeline.allEvents($http),
           Timeline.allTimeSlots($http)]).then(function (returnValues) {
               Timeline.constructedTotalTimeline(returnValues)
           });
```

The Timeline.construcedTotalTimeline should be called with the results of both async calls. The function only receives the first object however (the one returned by Timeline.allEvents).
What am I missing here?

Comment: if you call the `then` function for debug pour poses only on `Timeline.allTimeSlots($http)` does it function properly?

Comment: are both of your functions returning promises?

Comment: Yes, both functions work independently and both return promises.

Comment: The code in its brevity is correct. So, do they insist on the same destination server? Does the backend server send back data to both the $http requests with no error? You can use any packet inspector like wireshark to do this.

Comment: @morels: The backend is correct. What happens right now is that the q.all is acting like a foreach, first doing the call, then  calling the constructedTotalTimeLine twice (once per promise).

Comment: It is not possible because if you give an array as input to `$q.all(...)` it returns you an array (say `returnValues `) with an ordered list of answers to your promises. Moreover it only runs the then callback if and only if EVERY promises returns with no fault. Did you include the "$q" module of the native AJS?

Comment: It turned out I left a testing in the constructedTotalTime function (which i controlled before that and deemed 100% correct -_-). Sorry for wasting your and my time. It's working now. Thanks for all the replies!